# jquery - closest seems not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code something like that :

```
<div class="fieldset clearfix">
<h2 class="fieldset_title">Title <i class="indicator glyphicon  pull-right glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></h2>
<div class="fieldsgroup_info"></div>

<div class="fieldsgroup">
....
</div>
</div>
```

When I do in jquery

```
$('.fieldset_title').click(function(){
    $( this ).closest( ".fieldsgroup" ).hide();
});
```

Seems not working, do you have an idea why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: You should read about [jQuery closest() method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.fieldsGroup` is the sibling of `.fieldset_title` not its parent, so replace

```
$( this ).closest( ".fieldsgroup" ).hide();
```

with [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$( this ).siblings( ".fieldsgroup" ).hide();
```

Or as suggested by **A.Wolff** in his comment below

```
$( this ).nextAll(".fieldsgroup").first().hide();
```

Comment: `newtUntil()` doesn't include element matching passed selector

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, it returns elements untill the passed selector. Removed it, thanks

Comment: And btw `next()` won't work in OP's case, you could use instead `.nextAll(".fieldsgroup").first().hide()` or i guess `siblings()` as in your example would be enough